# About creating an object inside array and deleting an object from a array using mongoose package in discord bot

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

This feature is like storing real-life money in a bank (using bot) for each server, called wallet and only admins can addmoney or removemoney from someone's wallet. 1st cmd is `wallet open` for admin to open the wallet for their server.
Second is
`wallet register` which will be used by the users. A wallet will be opened for them in the server and it will be stored inside the wallet array so anyone can check their balance by `wallet balance @Ping/name`. Admins can addmoney and removemoney from their bank. Another admin command to get a list of all users' names and how much money they have in their wallet.

There will be another command to reset every user's wallet to 0. I mean 0 amount.

Why is this wallet? Many Indian servers do daily 4-5 and weekly tournaments. So they need to pay the users and to pay, they need to store how much did the users win. This wallet idea is for the Indian servers. When someone wins they can just add and remove money to their account. After everything is paid they can set it again to 0 amount and generate a list when they need to pay them.

Schema file
https://sourceb.in/08007d1d2d

```
{

   "_id":"dabtabase stuff",

   "guild":"guild ID",

   "wallets":[

      {

         "id":"user ID",

         "amount":0,

         "date":"date"

      },

      {

         "id":"everytime a new user registers a bank his data will be created like this",

         "amount":0,

         "date":"date"

      },

      {

         "id":"everytime a new user registers a bank his data will be created like this",

         "amount":0,

         "date":"date"

      }

   ]

}
```

This is how the doc looks like in MongoDB
and this is my main wallets.js code :/
https://sourceb.in/674aa83ed6
and yes, I am a beginner, I mean not a pro, and I am still learning JS

Answer (score 0):

To set everyone's amount to zero, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
// example array
const wallets = [
  {
    amount: 0,
  }, {
    amount: 5,
  }, {
    amount: 7,
  }, {
    amount: 15,
  }, {
    amount: 22
  }
];

console.log('Before Reset: ', wallets);

wallets.forEach((wallet) => wallet.amount = 0);

console.log('After Reset: ', wallets);
```